# How to wrap tanstack/router Link with another component while keeping type safety

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tanstack, tanstack-router

I would like to wrap the Link component from Tanstack Router with another component and be able to pass this component the props that are needed to be passed to the Link component.

I.e. I want to make a reusable that uses wraps an external button with the Tanstack Router Link

Something like this

```
import { Link, LinkOptions } from '@tanstack/router'

interface ButtonLinkProps {
  // how do I make this type safe, it results to `string | undefined` instead of valid routes I have defined
  to: LinkOptions['to']
  children: string
}

export function ButtonLink(props: ButtonLinkProps) {
  return (
    <Link to={props.to} params={{}} search={{}}>
      <Button component='span'>{props.children}</Button>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

When using the Link component directly the value passed to the `to` prop can only be one of the defined routes. However I'm not sure how define the `to` prop in my own defined component to achieve the same result.

```
// How do I achieve the same type safety I would get if I would use Link directly
<ButtonLink to='/'>Link</ButtonLink>
```

Comment: What's the issue? Is there any error?

Comment: The issue is that in the ButtonLink `to` prop I can pass in any string, including non-available routes, whereas when I would use the Link directly typescript will give an error on invalid routes.

Comment: Did you find a solution of how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Found the following solution that works for me on version `0.0.1-beta.104`, assuming my `ButtonLink` component in the OP:

```
interface ButtonLinkProps {
  to: MakeLinkOptions['to']
  children: string
}
```

or if we simply want all props that can be provided to a Link

```
interface ButtonLinkProps extends MakeLinkOptions {
  children: string
}
```

Comment: It seems like ` "@tanstack/react-router": "^1.2.2"` version doesn't export `MakeLinkOptions` anymore

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how it can be used with `"@tanstack/react-router": "^1.2.2"`

```js
import { AnyRoute, Link, LinkProps, RegisteredRouter, RoutePaths } from "@tanstack/react-router";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export function CustomLink<
  TRouteTree extends AnyRoute = RegisteredRouter['routeTree'],
  TFrom extends RoutePaths<TRouteTree> | string = string,
  TTo extends string = '',
  TMaskFrom extends RoutePaths<TRouteTree> | string = TFrom, TMaskTo extends string = ''
>({
  linkProps,
  children,
}: {
  linkProps: LinkProps<TRouteTree, TFrom, TTo, TMaskFrom, TMaskTo> & React.RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
  children: ReactNode
}) {
  return <Link {...linkProps}>{children}</Link>
}
```

Then, it can be used like

```js
function Main() {
  return (
    <CustomLink linkProps={{ to: "/$param", params: { foo: "foo" } }}>
      Click here
    </CustomLink>
  )
}
```

P.S. Honestly, I don't know what all these types mean, but it was suggested on the React-Router Discord channel.

This answer is a also [duplicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77789323/7291317).

Answer (score 0):

my latest and best solution..

```
import { Link as TsrLink, LinkOptions, RegisteredRouter } from "@tanstack/react-router";

type RT = RegisteredRouter["routeTree"];

export const Link = <TTo extends string = ".">({
  size,
  ...props
}: LinkOptions<RT, "/", TTo> & ExtraProps) => (
  <TsrLink
    {...sxp(sx.base, size && sx[size])}
    {...props}
    activeProps={{
      className: "font-bold",
    }}
  />
);
```