# How to wrap a Link component with type safety?

Tags: tanstack-router

There is a [Link](https://tanstack.com/router/v1/docs/api/router/linkComponent) component in [@tanstack/react-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tanstack/react-router). I want to nest (wrap) this component into my own component(s).

How can I do this and keep the type-safety which it provides?

This is example of the structure

```js
interface ContainerProps {
  to: // What type should be here?
  param: // What type should be here?
}


function Container (props: ContainerProps) {
  return <WrappedLink to={props.to} params={props.params} />
}

interface WrapperProps {
 // What should be here?
}

function WrappedLink(props: PropsWithChildren<WrapperProps>) {
  return <Link {...props}>{props.children}</Link>
}
```

This is how it should be used

```js
function Page() {
  const params = page1.useParams()

  return <Container to={page2.to} params={params.foo} /> // NOTE: TypeScript should autosuggest what values are available
}
```

This is component hierarchy for simplicity

```
Page (pass `to` & `params`)
- Container (pass `to` & `params`)
 - Wrapper (pass `to` & `params`)
  - Link
```

P.S. I checked other posts here on StackOverflow, but didn't find a solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of how it can be used with `"@tanstack/react-router": "^1.2.2"`

```js
import { AnyRoute, Link, LinkProps, RegisteredRouter, RoutePaths } from "@tanstack/react-router";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export function CustomLink<
  TRouteTree extends AnyRoute = RegisteredRouter['routeTree'],
  TFrom extends RoutePaths<TRouteTree> | string = string,
  TTo extends string = '',
  TMaskFrom extends RoutePaths<TRouteTree> | string = TFrom, TMaskTo extends string = ''
>({
  linkProps,
  children,
}: {
  linkProps: LinkProps<TRouteTree, TFrom, TTo, TMaskFrom, TMaskTo> & React.RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
  children: ReactNode
}) {
  return <Link {...linkProps}>{children}</Link>
}
```

Then, it can be used like

```js
function Main() {
  return (
    <CustomLink linkProps={{ to: "/$param", params: { foo: "foo" } }}>
      Click here
    </CustomLink>
  )
}
```

P.S. Honestly, I don't know what all these types mean, but it was suggested on the React-Router Discord channel.

Answer (score 0):

I assume due to updates to the lib the previous answer is no longer squiggly-free. After much shotgunning I stumbled upon `LinkComponent` and that seems to be working for me..

```
import { Link as TsrLink, LinkComponent } from "@tanstack/react-router";

export const Link: LinkComponent<"a"> = (props) => <TsrLink {...props} />;
```

[image: Screenshot of link implementation and usage demonstrating type safety]

**Edit..**

I wanted to add more props for styling so went back and managed to update the "MakeLinkOptions" answer provided by Tanner Linsley in a Github ticket..

It does only appear to be link-specific props that are included though, so `children`, `style`, and probably others still need to be added.

Also, `Link` from the router seems to be ok with absolute urls, but my wrapper has lost that and complains.

```
import { Link as TsrLink, LinkOptions, RegisteredRouter } from "@tanstack/react-router";

type ExtraProps = {
  size?: "sm" | "md" | "lg";
  children: ReactNode;
};

type RT = RegisteredRouter["routeTree"];

export const Link = <TTo extends string = ".">({
  size,
  ...props
}: LinkOptions<RT, "/", TTo> & ExtraProps) => (
  <TsrLink
    {...sxp(sx.base, size && sx[size])}
    {...props}
    activeProps={{
      className: "font-bold",
    }}
  />
);
```